# Can't show title of reference (many) content type from Contentful (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, reference, one-to-many, contentful

Hey i have content_type category with two fields - title and subcategory.Sub category is reference with option many, but when i try to show all subcategories i have error in console "Can't read property 'title' of undefined". I can't figure why.

In my contentful-api service i have :

```
getCategory(query?: object): Promise<EntryCollection<Category>> {
return this.clientApi.getEntries<Category>(
  Object.assign({}, query, { content_type: 'categories', include: 2})
);
```

}

After that in my component.ts file i have :

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

  categories: Array<Entry<Category>>;

  constructor(private contentfulApiService: ContentfulApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.contentfulApiService
      .getCategory()
      .then((categories) => (this.categories = categories.items));
  }
}
```

And in my component.html :

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let category of categories">
      {{ category.fields.subCategories.fields.title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

If i switch reference to single from Contentful, everything works. But i need to be many so i can assign many subcategories and show it all.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> Can't read property 'title' of undefined

Means that you're trying to access the `title` attribute of something that's undefined. Looking at your code it can only be this line.

```
{{ category.fields.subCategories.fields.title }}
```

I'm assuming that `subCategories` is a collection and thus an `array`. An `array` wouldn't have a `fields` property (it's undefined). That's why `title` can not be accessed – because it's `undefined`.

If that's really the case, and it is really a collection you probably want to iterate again over all the `subCategories` to access the fields and titles of every sub category.